# How to iterate through tuples in a file

Tags: python, tuples

I'm working on a project for my NLP class and this point I have a .txt file that looks like this:

```
(u'I', u'PRON')(u'am', u'VERB')(u'nobody', u'NOUN')(u':', u'.')(u'A', u'DET')(u'red', u'ADJ')(u'sinking', u'NOUN')(u'autumn', u'NOUN')(u'sun', u'NOUN')(u'Took', u'NOUN')(u'my', u'PRON')(u'name', u'NOUN')(u'away', u'ADV')(u'.', u'.')(u'Keep', u'VERB')(u'straight', u'VERB')(u'down', u'PRT')(u'this', u'DET')(u'block', u'NOUN')....
```

So basically, it's just a bunch of tuples with a word and a tag. I'm trying to iterate through this file and return a list of just things tagged with "NOUN."

So, the output may look like: `["nobody," "autumn",....]`

I am really unsure how to iterate through these tuples and more so get rid of that u' tag. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering you have the data in a text file, here is a solution using regex:

```
import re
data = """(u'I', u'PRON')(u'am', u'VERB')(u'nobody', u'NOUN')(u':', u'.')(u'A', u'DET')(u'red', u'ADJ')(u'sinking', u'NOUN')(u'autumn', u'NOUN')(u'sun', u'NOUN')(u'Took',u'NOUN')(u'my', u'PRON')(u'name', u'NOUN')(u'away', u'ADV')(u'.', u'.')(u'Keep', u'VERB')(u'straight', u'VERB')(u'down', u'PRT')(u'this',u'DET')(u'block', u'NOUN')'s = r"(u'I', u'PRON')(u'am', u'VERB')(u'nobody', u'NOUN')(u':', u'.')(u'A', u'DET')(u'red', u'ADJ')(u'sinking', u'NOUN')(u'autumn', u'NOUN')(u'sun', u'NOUN')(u'Took', u'NOUN')(u'my', u'PRON')(u'name', u'NOUN')(u'away', u'ADV')(u'.', u'.')(u'Keep', u'VERB')(u'straight',u'VERB')(u'down', u'PRT')(u'this', u'DET')(u'block', u'NOUN')"""
#Use regex to get the split the data as required
rx = re.compile(r"\(u'(.*?)'\,\su'(.*?)'\)")
#Find all the matches
matches = rx.findall(s)
tuples = []
for match in matches:
    tuples.append(match)

#Get the nouns from the list of tuples  
nouns = [ x for x in tuples if "NOUN" in x]
```

Following image shows the results produced:
[image]

Comment: You have a stray quote somehwere

Comment: The stray quote issue has been fixed. @Natecat - Thank you for pointing it.

Answer (score 1):

Use a list comprehension to decompose all tuples,apply the str function to the word to convert it to a string instead of unicode, and filter out words based on their type:

`output=[str(word) for word,wtype in tuplist if wtype.lower()=='noun']`

A little tip is using the lower function to standardize strings to check conditions. If you think you will have rogue whitespace, you can also use strip() right after it like:
`wtype.lower().strip()=='noun'`

Comment: I'm not sure what you think `str()` does, but in python 3, it [stays unicode](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#text-sequence-type-str). Additionally, what is the point of using lower or strip in this case? OP shows no varience in case or whitespace

Comment: Strip is just a tip for him. You won't always get clean data. Doesn't hurt to know. He wanted the u removed, he gets it via str, assuming it's 2. I don't really see your point.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a list comprehension to do this, such as this one:

```
lst = [i[0] for i in tuples if i[1] == "NOUN"]
```

List comprehension syntax is a little confusing, so here is it's equivalent for loop

```
lst=[]
for i in tuples:
    if i[1] == "NOUN":
        lst.append(i)
```

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you will first get the lines from text and replace all u' with '. Then you can iterate through the tuples like this;

```
x = [('I', 'PRON'), ('am', 'VERB'), ('nobody', 'NOUN')] // that would be lines of your text file.
array = []
for element in x:
    first, second = element
    if second == "NOUN":
        array.append(first)

print array
```